# How to read TENTATIVE flag of IPv6 Address?

Tags: c, linux, ipv6

I am assigning ipv6 address using ioctl() system call prgramtically.
I want to know if there is a way, i can find the assigned ip is tentative/duplicate ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Host:  Enumerate the interfaces with `getifaddrs()`.

(**edit**) Looks like you need to call `sysctl(NET_IPV6_OPT_DAD_ENABLE)` before `getifaddrs()`?

http://lwn.net/Articles/218597/

Network:  Send an ICMP ping is the typical but not fool proof method that DHCP servers use.

It is assumed if you are setting the IP then you are implementing a form of DHCP and you control all the addresses for that segment.  Otherwise just use the link-local scope already unique addresses.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am checking on the host. I assign the IPv6 address and then i want to know if it is not tentative/duplicate.
The getifaddrs() function gives only SIOCGIFFLAGS in which IFA_F_TENTATIVE doesn't exist. The "ip" command tells me if the IP is tentative using the command "ip addr show <interface name>

Comment: I am going through the sources of iproute package which constitutes "ip". Didn't have any luck though... :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can read TENTATIVE flag of IPv6 Address as below:

Indicates flags that are set on the multicast address. As of RFC 2373, the only flag defined is the Transient (T) flag. The T flag uses the low-order bit of the Flags field.

```
* If 0, the multicast address is a permanently assigned, well-known multicast address allocated by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA).
* If 1, the multicast address is a not permanently assigned, or transient.
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your response.
I think, that works only for multi-cast IPv6 addresses. It's not for Link-local,site-local and global addresses i guess. But, i am able to use netlink sockets to retrieve the flags though.

Regards,
-Krishna

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the state of the address is to use the rtnetlink library via the RTM_GETADDR message which retrieves the ifaddrmsg structure which contains ifa_flags. Look at the man page here for information:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html

The flags and ifaddrmsg structure are shown in if_addr.h:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/if_addr.h